# Authentication in react native gone wrong

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication

Please help, I have a login Screen in react native which seems to be working but when i input the correct credentials for a user, it keeps saying Invalid Username/Password as i ask it to do if the credential is wrong, but it does that even when its correct now. I notice when i use react native debugger it will work perfectly. I dont know what could be the problem

LoginScreen

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import * as Yup from "yup";

import Screen from "../components/Screen";
import {
  AppForm,
  AppFormField,
  ErrorMessage,
  SubmitButton,
} from "../components/forms";
import authApi from "../api/auth";
import useAuth from "../auth/useAuth";

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  username: Yup.string().required().label("Username"),
  password: Yup.string().required().min(4).label("Password"),
});

function LoginScreen(props) {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const [loginFailed, setLoginFailed] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async ({ username, password }) => {
    const result = await authApi.login(username, password);
    if (!result.ok) return setLoginFailed(true);
    setLoginFailed(false);
    // console.log(result.data.access);
    auth.logIn(result.data.access);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Screen style={styles.container}>
        <Image styles={styles.logo} source={require("../assets/logo2.png")} />
        <AppForm
          initialValues={{ username: "", password: "" }}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
        >
          <ErrorMessage
            error="Invalid username and/or password."
            visible={loginFailed}
          />
          <AppFormField
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            icon="account"
            // keyboardType="email-address"
            name="username"
            placeholder="Username"
            textContentType="emailAddress"
          />

          <AppFormField
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            icon="lock"
            name="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry
            textContentType="password"
          />
          <SubmitButton title="Login" />
        </AppForm>
      </Screen>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```js
authApi.login(username, password).then(() =>{
   // Your code here...
})
```

or

```js
const result = authApi.login(username, password);

    if ((typeof result.ok === "boolean") && !result.ok) {
         setLoginFailed(true);
       } else {
         setLoginFailed(false);
         auth.logIn(result.data.access);
       }
```

or you can try to check your **result.ok**:

```js
console.log(typeof result);
```

Comment: Remove await if you use .then/.catch

Comment: ...unless returning value from .then() that you want to use inline

Comment: Okay this is a good step, but it returns "undefined in the console. its supposed to return a token

Comment: Hi guys please I still need your help, I just saw the craziest thing since i started coding, So i noticed that when i use my code as it is from the question and i use react-native debugger tool, it works. but if i want to run it directly it shows the error. I dont understand it and its is the same credentials for both cases